# Run .txt file using java

Tags: java, windows, notepad

I want to open a txt file using java

For running .exe I use this:

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\windows\\notepad.exe");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have tried to run .txt file and it doesn't work. I get IOException with this message:

```
CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

How I can run a .txt using java?

Comment: What is "running a .txt file"  ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean - start a (default) text editor and open designated file in it or read the contents of a text file in your Java application?

Comment: Start a (default) text editor and open designated file in it

Comment: I would like to know why you try to `execute` a textfile. You can't, but you can pass it as an argument to other executables within exec command, in example to open it with text editors. See javadoc for `Runtime.getRuntime.exec` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "run" a `.txt` file. Because a text file simply respresents a set of characters with a certain encoding. Whereas on the other hand an exe is a file containing compiled code. That is information specifically for the machine to understand.

If, like in your example above, you want to open a textfile in Notepad, you have a few options. One goes as follows

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "c:\\windows\\notepad.exe", "C:\\path\\to\\the.txt" });
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I'm on windows and with "start" don't work. But I don't want to open in default program. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad is already set in your `PATH` environment variable, you miss only the paremeter: the file to be opened:

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("start notepad 'PATH/TO/file.txt'");
```

FYI notepad argument list:

```
/A <filename> open file as ansi
/W <filename> open file as unicode
/P <filename> print filename
/PT <filename> <printername> <driverdll> <port> print filename to designated printer
```